# Add watermark on pdf, from google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, watermark

I'm creating a pdf from google app script and i'm saving that in google drive, before crating pdf, i want to add a watermark, "TEAM MYNAME" and then finally save it to drive.

function to create a pdf and save it in g-drive

```
function savePDF() {

  var content = '<span style="font-size: 20px;">Hello, this is a sample pdf</span>';
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(content).getContent();

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlBody, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName('digest.pdf');
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);

}
```

this is working, but i want to add a watermark. can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Asked before: [GAS-watermark-3rd-party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220133/google-spreadsheet-to-pdf-with-watermark-in-google-script)

Another workaround mentioned here: [GAS-watermark-workaround](http://alicekeeler.com/2014/09/10/create-a-background-image-or-watermark-on-a-google-doc/)