# Add watermark to PDF using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, google-app-maker

I am working on a Document Approval Workflow in Appmaker, I have a use case where If document gets approved then I need to convert that Google Doc to PDF and Add watermark (Confidential text) to it. I have successfully converted my Google Document to PDF By following code,

```
var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFileById('docId').getAs(MimeType.PDF);
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this? I think possible way out is

1. Using Third party end point to which I can pass my PDF and get
   'Confidential' text embedded in the background as watermark

Please suggest if there is any other way out.

P.S. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220133/google-spreadsheet-to-pdf-with-watermark-in-google-script) is outdated and that REST End point is no longer working

**EDIT:**
This is how my final PDF should look like.
[image: Sample output]

Comment: Could you please add image/mockup how the final PDF should look like?

Comment: @tehhowch : Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my question.

Comment: @PavelShkleinik : I've updated my question and added sample PDF.

Comment: Can you include SDKs in your appmaker project? If so, there's always Adobe :) You might have better luck if you go the `docs -> Word -> watermark -> PDF` route, though depending on your document that could get distorted