# Can I integrate SMS gateway in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I am looking for an option to integrate SMS gateway in App Maker 
On form submit genrate an OTP and verify the OTP To confirm the Mobile Number

Comment: Do you have any REST exposed which can send SMS when consumed? You can consume REST in Appmaker using Appscript, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220133/google-spreadsheet-to-pdf-with-watermark-in-google-script) for how to consume REST in Appscript?

Comment: Someone has just posted his SMS integration using Apps script. Please refer 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763550/google-sheets-script-sending-twilio-sms-messages-works-when-run-manually-but-fai) and [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html)