# Google sheets script sending twilio SMS messages works when run manually but fails when triggered by time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, twilio

I am trying to build a google sheets spreadsheet to send SMS reminders. At this stage, I'm still just building the basics of sending SMS from google sheets. I have replaced some fields with their names, eg the API SID and token, and my phone number. My code is below:

```js
//At the moment this seems to work when manually run, but not when triggered by time or whatever.


function sendSms(to, body) {
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/API_SID_GOES_HERE/Messages.json"; //This contains my Twilio API LIVE SID
 
  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : body,
    "From" : "61123456789" //This is the twilio phone number
  };
 
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };
 
  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("API_LIVE_TOKEN_GOES_HERE") //This contains my Twilio API LIVE Token
  };
 
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}
 
function sendAll() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID_NUMBER") //This part is the ID number of the spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[2]); //This little feller sets an active sheet which it manipulates. Sheet count starts from [0]
  var startRow = 2; //starts counting from row #2
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) //getRange(Integer row, Integer column, Integer numRows, Integer numColumns)
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); //Gets just the values of the cells, not the formulas
 
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    try {
      response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
      status = "sent";
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      status = "error";
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 4).setValue(status); //The number after (i), is the column where the setValue(Status) will land.
  }
}
 
function myFunction() {
  sendAll();
}
```

It seems that if I run the code manually, it works fine, sends an SMS, updates the 'status' field and all is well. However, if I set a trigger for the script, be it a fixed time trigger or an every minute trigger, the script fails. The Summary of Failures that google apps script sends me is:

> Request failed for
>   https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER/Messages.json
>   returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code": 21211,
>   "message": "The 'To' number is not a valid phone number.",
>   "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "status":
>   400} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line
>   19, file "Code")

I can't quite figure out why. I think it has something to do with var spreadsheet and var sheet, but I really don't know.

Most of the code has been copied from [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html) twilio blog post.

Comment: I don't think so it has any issue with Time base/Manual trigger. Error clearly stats that there is some problem with the `TO` number. Add loggerin `sendSms` function and print `TO` number before sending SMS and then try time based trigger once. Also cross check your sheet data once.

Comment: Howdy, so I went ahead and added some logging to my code, I set it to output the 'to' variable to a particular cell on my sheet. When I run my code manually, it populates that cell with the correct phone number, and the SMS goes through successfully. When I then add a trigger condition, that logging cell is populated with '{authMode=FULL, week-of-year=32, day-of-week=4, month=8, hour=12, year=2018, timezone=UTC, day-of-month=9, triggerUid=1048705414, minute=0, second=59}', and I get the same failure summary email from google, and no SMS.

Comment: Oh!! Share your Sheet if possible. Look for formatting for those cells once as well

Comment: This is it, it's extremely basic. Just a header row, a data row, three columns of data, and '6,6' is just an out of the way place where I dumped the log output: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BFUzQ7-w-I-01wpOIxXO8aBUJ6_neneDZ0229ApZDQY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why are you using `setActiveSheet` in a triggered function? Just use `getSheetByName`. Time-based triggers have no UI instance associated with their execution, so my thought is that you are accessing the values on the first sheet during the triggered run. This should have been immediately apparent if you log the sheet name and the row data before consuming it...

Comment: That was part of my troubleshooting, I thought at first the issue had to do with my workbook having multiple sheets, and the wrong sheet was being targeted when the script ran automatically (which it actually was, but that was an unrelated bug) - I've since replaced it with -  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("WORKBOOK_ID") | 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Badger");

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, and it was something terribly obvious.

When setting up the trigger, I had completely overlooked the need to define which function I wanted it to trigger. By default, it was just running function sendSMS, which, at that point, had not been fed any data to send.

So my manual runs were running the function called myFunction, but the triggered runs were running sendSMS.

[image]

Once I realized this, and changed it, it worked just fine.

Thanks to all those who contributed for their help, especially Darpan for chasing the red herring with me.

Comment: Glad to help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the twilio ling to the 2016 post as well as the code submited above. However I still ran into errors and was able to use a simular fix. instead of setting the trigger to use Myfunction I set it to use the sendAll function and worked like a charm. below is the code I used.

```js
function sendSms(to, body) {
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/++insert your account sid here ++/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : "Our Thanks For Signing Up", //body,
    "From" : "++ your twillio number here. remember it must begin with the "+" "
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("++insert your account sid here ++:++insert your account token here ++")
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}

function sendAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    try {
      response_data = sendSms(row[0], row[1]);
      status = "sent";
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      status = "error";
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 3).setValue(status);
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  sendAll();
}
```